# How to wire a ceiling rose that has 7 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I'm trying to rewire a ceiling rose, and I made the very silly mistake of not photographing or checking the initial wiring before I took the previous fitting down.

I seem to have 7 wires coming in through 2 cables. I can't seem to find any information about what to do in this situation - every diagram I find is for more or less wires!

The light point is on its own circuit, though I think the original installer may have thought there were multiple lights on the circuit. What should I be wiring to the Live & Neutral of the light (I know where Earth goes!)? Should any of the wires be looping (I think so?)?

Photos attached of ceiling wires and switch wires (it's the switch with the grey & brown pair of wires I believe - second one down).

[image: Switch wiring]
[image: Ceiling wiring]

Comment: Where are you ? That would be odd coloring forthe US..

Comment: Makes sense - not in the US! Am in the UK.

Comment: Yeah, you will definitely need a UK electrician to answer your question. The normal color code we follow here in the USA does not have brown wire in a cable with blue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this, so posting here for anyone else in future:

cable A blue to light fitting N
cable A brown to loop

cable B brown to loop
cable B grey with brown tape to light fitting L
cable B black to light fitting N (along with blue from cable A).

Comment: Seems ok. *Normally* the cable B brown would take live from the loop, take it down to the switch, and be connected (via the switch) to the grey (with brown tape - to show that it is potentially live). In your situation I really can't see clearly what's happening at the switch; certainly the switches are all sharing a live, which then makes me wonder why there's also a loop at the ceiling fitting... seems a bit weird to me, but I'm a DIYer and not a qualified electrician.